# Passing lists from Mathematica to c++ (Mathlink)

Tags: c++, wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I simply want to pass a list of integers to a function written in C++. I've set up the template (.tm) file and all, and I can successfully call a test function whith scalar arguments. Calling the function with the list argument behaves as though the function was not defined at all. I suspect that the argument types don't match.

In the documentation for templates (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/file.tm.html) the datatype for lists is something like "Int32List". When I use that, my C++ function must contain an extra long parameter for the list length. The only example code which uses a list is "sumalist.tm". This example uses IntegerList (a type which doesn't appear in the doku).

When I use Int32List, the mprep result requires a function with an extra integer argument (not long as written in the doku). When I use the undocumented IntegerList type, the extra argument is of type long.

During my experiments with scalar types, I had a similar problem - a c++ function was called properly when using "Integer" in the tm-file, and not recognized with "Integer32".

The "sumalist.tm" example also uses a strange Pattern (list:{___Integer}) about which I didn't find any documentation. I'd also like to understand what the Evaluate line means (I suspect that it's used make the function callable without the curly braces around the list).

So who know which datatypes are really appropriate to call a c++ function with a list - maybe also with reals... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about MathLink, but I can explain the pattern, `list:{___Integer}`.

The colon is just the general form for a named pattern, that is `symbol:pattern` just says that the object referred to by `symbol` has to match `pattern`. Indeed, pattern like `a_Integer` or `b__List` are really just short forms for `a:_Integer` and `b:__List`.

So what we are left with interpreting is `{___Integer}`. This is a pattern matching a list of arbitrary many (including zero) integers. It works as follows:

`{Pattern}` is the Pattern for a list whose contents matches `Pattern`

`___Integer` is the Pattern for a sequence of zero or more `Integer`s.

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation - it clears things up by a lot.

Answer (score 5):

The mapping of MathLink data types (e.g., `Integer32`, `Integer32List`, ...) to C/C++ types is described on the [MathLink template file](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/file.tm.html) documentation page.

The page no longer documents the old interface types `Integer`, `Real`, `IntegerList` and `RealList`. These should no longer be used, because the mapping of these types depends on C types whose bit length is platform and compiler dependent (e.g., `long`). Use the corresponding new type with explicit bit length instead (i.e., `Integer32` or `Integer64` instead of `Integer`). The old interface types are still documented in the somewhat dated [MathLink reference](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3710/MathLinkRef.pdf) guide.

The following [talk slides](http://www.unisoftwareplus.com/download/talks/Wien2011/Developing%20on%20the%20Mathematica%20Platform.zip) contain a simple MathLink example that shows how to implement a MathLink function that adds a scalar value to a vector of reals. This may serve as a starting point.

Comment: No it's not, at least not in depth. As I wrote, the "easy" case (scalar arguments) works for me after some trial and error, but I can't find any details about passing list arguments. And on the page you (and I) linked there's a contradiction: When I click "More Information" a list of datatypes appears, which does *not* contain "Integer". In the following example, "Integer" ist used. As I found out by experiment, mprep accepts both, but only Integer actually works. So what's this Integer32 business?

Comment: @Batox I have updated my answer with links that provide more information and a MathLink example.